# Qt Drawing Lines

Tags: qt, graphics, drawing, qt-creator

I am learning Qt, and I want to draw lines randomly on a widget and keep appending the new lines. The code below draws a random line in the paintEvent whenever an update is called on the widget, but how do I stop the widget from clearing the previously drawn line when paintEvent is called? Is there any way to just append drawn objects?

Obviously I could store all the lines and repaint them every time, but that seems unnecessary for what I will be doing with this application.

```
void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QPainter painter(this);

        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 2));

        painter.drawLine(QPointF(qrand() % 300, qrand() % 300), QPointF(qrand() % 300,qrand() % 300));
}



void MainWindow::on_b_toggleDrawing_triggered()
{
    this->update();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could draw the lines on an off-screen surface and [blit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_blit) them to the widget in the paint event. A [QImage](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qimage.html) would be ideal as it is a [QPaintDevice](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qpaintdevice.html) and could be drawn using [QPainter::drawImage](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qpainter.html#drawImage). The snippet below assumes that `this->image` is a pointer to a QImage with the same size as the MainWindow.

```
void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QPainter painter(this);

    painter.drawImage(this->rect, *this->image);
}

void MainWindow::on_b_toggleDrawing_triggered()
{
    QPainter painter(this->image);

    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 2));
    painter.drawLine(QPointF(qrand() % 300, qrand() % 300),
                     QPointF(qrand() % 300,qrand() % 300));

    this->update();
}
```

An alternative would be to build a path using [QPainterPath](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qpainterpath.html#details). In that case, you would simply maintain a QPainterPath instance, add lines as needed and then draw the path in the paint event handler. I'm not as familiar with painter paths. So, I'm not sure how the performance compares with the previous approach.

Comment: This seems to work, but it is pretty slow on a full size window since it has to basically copy the entire screen. It is better to just redraw hundreds/thousands of lines. I'll give the QPainterPath a try too when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Set [`autoFillBackground`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qwidget.html#autoFillBackground-prop) to false. It's erasing (filling with background color) before calling `paintEvent` if set.

Answer (score 0):

Or, insert command

```
 this->setAttribute( Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground, bool ) ;
```

prior to calling

```
 this->update() ;
```

bool = true - leaves the paint area intact and allows 
              new items to be added to the paint area.

bool = false - erases the paint area before drawing items.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you want to create the next line you could create a [`QGraphicsLineItem` (link)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicslineitem.html) object and add it to a [`QGraphicsScene` (link)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html) widget.

Note that in this solution you have to bother neither about repainting the lines nor about destroying them when quitting the program, because `QGraphicsScene` will take care of both actions.